# Where does Unity save Inspector properties for objects in a scene?

Tags: unity

If I add a collection of objects to my scene and configure Inspector properties on those objects (like name, layer, tag, transform parameters, attached Components and their parameters), where does the information about those Inspector properties get saved within my project?

Is it all saved within the scene's `.unity` file or are there other files I should look at?

Comment: Are you asking how to save properties or their location? You just need to save the scene to remember any alterations to properties in the inspector window. As for their location it's usually on the right hand side when you select the corresponding GameObject.

Comment: when u select an Object in unity, inspector show all property and value ... so  where those property and value store? i mean its must saved in a file in somewhere...

Comment: why you want to know this?

Answer (score 4):

While this question is a couple of months old, the existing answer is not correct.

It describes how to reveal and inspect Unity's `.meta` files, which by default are hidden. However, these do *not* contain the inspector properties of objects in a scene. Those are stored in the `.unity` files corresponding to the scenes themselves.

---

What `.meta` files contain:

- A file format version, for compatibility in reading the meta file itself.
- A [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier), used to identify assets when they're referenced within other assets.

  This is why renaming an asset in Unity doesn't force all references to it to be updated or break - they're looked up by ID, which remains constant once an asset has been created, as long as you don't separate it from its `.meta` file.
- Import settings for asset files like textures, models, or sounds - these are the settings you see in the Inspector when selecting the resource in your Project folder.
- User data, creation timestamp, and asset bundle information for scene (`.unity`) or prefab (`.prefab`) files.
- Execution order, creation timestamp, and asset bundle information for script (`.cs` & `.js`) files.

---

So `.meta` files do *not* include any of the object properties mentioned in the question: "name, layer, tag, transform parameters, attached Components and their parameters."

How do we find these?

First, go to `Edit -> Project Settings -> Editor` and change "Asset Serialization Mode" to "Force Text," then save your scene & project. This takes scene and prefab data that would normally be saved in binary form and ensures it's written out in human-readable form in your project source files. (So far as I'm aware, this does not affect how assets are serialized in your compiled builds, but I have not tested this specifically)

Now, to find the object parameters for an object instance in one of your scenes, open that scene's `.unity` file in a text editor. Here you'll find data like this:

```
--- !u!1 &991079445
GameObject:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 0
  m_PrefabParentObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInternal: {fileID: 0}
  serializedVersion: 4
  m_Component:
  - 4: {fileID: 991079451}
  - 20: {fileID: 991079450}
  - 81: {fileID: 991079447}
  - 114: {fileID: 991079446}
  - 114: {fileID: 991079452}
  m_Layer: 0
  m_Name: Main Camera
  m_TagString: MainCamera
  m_Icon: {fileID: 0}
  m_NavMeshLayer: 0
  m_StaticEditorFlags: 0
  m_IsActive: 1
--- !u!114 &991079446
MonoBehaviour:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 0
  m_PrefabParentObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInternal: {fileID: 0}
  m_GameObject: {fileID: 991079445}
  m_Enabled: 1
  m_EditorHideFlags: 0
  m_Script: {fileID: 11500000, guid: 4911397511e5c054a92cf2f47bd376b6, type: 3}
  m_Name: 
  m_EditorClassIdentifier: 
  projection:
  - {x: 0.76, y: 0, z: 1425, w: 0}
  - {x: 0, y: 0.68, z: 0, w: 0}
  - {x: 0, y: 0, z: -1, w: -0.1}
  - {x: 0, y: 0, z: -1, w: 0}
  materialToAlter: {fileID: 2100000, guid: dfeebd5fa422c5144b13201e09d2b95b, type: 2}
--- !u!81 &991079447
AudioListener:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 0
  m_PrefabParentObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInternal: {fileID: 0}
  m_GameObject: {fileID: 991079445}
  m_Enabled: 1
--- !u!20 &991079450
Camera:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 0
  m_PrefabParentObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInternal: {fileID: 0}
  m_GameObject: {fileID: 991079445}
  m_Enabled: 1
  serializedVersion: 2
  m_ClearFlags: 1
  m_BackGroundColor: {r: 0.19215687, g: 0.3019608, b: 0.4745098, a: 0}
  m_NormalizedViewPortRect:
    serializedVersion: 2
    x: 0
    y: 0
    width: 1
    height: 1
  near clip plane: 0.3
  far clip plane: 20
  field of view: 60
  orthographic: 0
  orthographic size: 5
  m_Depth: -1
  m_CullingMask:
    serializedVersion: 2
    m_Bits: 4294967295
  m_RenderingPath: -1
  m_TargetTexture: {fileID: 0}
  m_TargetDisplay: 0
  m_TargetEye: 3
  m_HDR: 0
  m_OcclusionCulling: 1
  m_StereoConvergence: 10
  m_StereoSeparation: 0.022
  m_StereoMirrorMode: 0
--- !u!4 &991079451
Transform:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 0
  m_PrefabParentObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInternal: {fileID: 0}
  m_GameObject: {fileID: 991079445}
  m_LocalRotation: {x: 0.23492102, y: 0.16446818, z: -0.04036682, w: 0.9571483}
  m_LocalPosition: {x: -1.97, y: 2.95, z: -6.89}
  m_LocalScale: {x: 1, y: 1, z: 1}
  m_LocalEulerAnglesHint: {x: 27.58, y: 19.5, z: 0}
  m_Children: []
  m_Father: {fileID: 0}
  m_RootOrder: 0
--- !u!114 &991079452
MonoBehaviour:
  m_ObjectHideFlags: 0
  m_PrefabParentObject: {fileID: 0}
  m_PrefabInternal: {fileID: 0}
  m_GameObject: {fileID: 991079445}
  m_Enabled: 1
  m_EditorHideFlags: 0
  m_Script: {fileID: 11500000, guid: c1d02e8598764a64cbd19d248b4c9644, type: 3}
  m_Name: 
  m_EditorClassIdentifier: 
  material: {fileID: 2100000, guid: dfeebd5fa422c5144b13201e09d2b95b, type: 2}
  pass: -1
```

This describes my "Main Camera" object in a particular scene, as you can see from the line `m_Name: Main Camera`. You can see it has `Camera` and `Audio Listener` components attached, an associated `Transform`, and two custom `MonoBehaviour` scripts identified by GUID.

You'll find data with essentially the same format in the `.prefab` file corresponding to `GameObjects` you've saved as prefabs in your Project folders. When you include an instance of a prefab in a scene, the scene will reference that prefab by GUID, and include its local transform within the scene, as well as any parameters you changed on that instance without applying them back to the prefab.

Answer (score -3):

They are hidden by default.

If you change  "Edit/Project Settings/Version Control"'s value as Visible Meta Files instead of Hidden Meta Files, then you can see all values in the your project folder.

Example:
You have a Player object.
So, you will see "Player.meta file" inside the assets folder.

Comment: ok thanks for your answer... i cant find any object of my scene in project window in unity or explorer in windows ... but when i open my scene in notepad i see all of my object and their properties in a format like json...but im not sure if scene files is for store property of object in scene.

Comment: Sorry I said wrong.

Comment: @user94009 If you add a script to your game object, you can see it's values inside the assets folder.

Comment: Dont Worry Man, its Ok  :-)

Comment: This answer is not correct. Unity's `.meta` files do *not* contain the inspector properties of scene objects as described in the question - those are saved in the scenes' `.unity` files. I've added an answer elaborating on this distinction.